# Both my MacBook Pro 11,5 and my MacBook Air 5,2 no longer have a keyboard backlight after upgrade to Mojave

Tags: keyboard, mojave, backlight

Both upgraded to macOS Mojave 10.14.6 18G103 - It took me a while to notice on the MBP because I use it as a desktop with a wireless keyboard and a dust cover over the built-in keyboard, but I upgraded the MBA, noticed this on the first restart, and then came to see that the MBP has the same issue. 
Reset PRAM/NVRAM & SMC on the MBA, no change.

Any idea whether it's a known issue or what else I can try?

Comment: (I'm not on mojave, so I'm not seeing the same system preferences as you) but... is there any setting under keyboard that mentions auto dimming or auto adjusting levels that might be setting the value to low to notice?

Comment: Nothing I can find either under keyboard or accessibility. When I search for "keyboard" in the System Preferences search control there's one item called "illuminate keyboard", but it highlights the keyboard icon, which has no controls for illumination...

Comment: I forgot that Macbook air 5,2" was a thing... It came out weirdly late too (~2013). Like waaay after the whole mini laptop (netbook) craze of ~2008. I remember looking at that thing at an Apple store with disgust. Anyways, I have no idea how to fix it. It seems like this isn't a very common issue or at least I've not seen one where the "Automatically illuminate keyboard in low light" setting goes missing. My late 2012 MacBook air is running Mojave and the backlight is working fine. Do you see the stop symbol if you try to adjust the backlight manually from the keyboard?

Comment: 5,2 is an Apple model designation for a 13" model from mid-2012 (A1466).
There is no response on-screen, but I can see this on the console:

default 08:57:55.680716 -0400 kernel X86PlatformPlugin result 0
default 08:57:55.680721 -0400 kernel X86PlatformPlugin result 0

Comment: I think I had a brainfart, because that size makes no sense :) Pretty sure I was thinking 11". — I tried to dig deep for anything, but there doesn't seem to be any fixes or info aside from what you're already tried. Well other than rolling back to an older version or trying a reinstall. Your best clue is probably the missing setting and that console message. Though as far as I could gather, the message is kinda vague and doesn't point to one specific issue, but a ton of different hardware and sortware related issues.

Comment: Well I found the problem. Both (one started out as a clone of the other) were missing AppleSMCLMU.kext. Bit of a shell-game with booting from optional devices on a healthy machine to grab it & then install it on the troubled ones, but as soon as I loaded that kext both the keyboard backlight key functionality and the options in the preference pane came right back.

Comment: ..and just to be specific: What you need to do to restore the keyboard backlight is to reload AppleSMCLMU.kext, which may or may not work depending on whether your machine has successfully loaded AppleSMC.kext & AppleSMCRTC.kext, so find these three kexts on a healthy machine with the same OS and put them someplace safe (because they disappear for no apparent reason from /System/Library/Extensions). Then load them with kextload. kextload might complain that ownership or permissions are not right, and direct you will need to "chown -R root:wheel ./AppleSMC.kext" before proceeding.